# assign value to a new list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have a class called Company

```
public class Company 
{
   public string name;
   public string id;
}
```

I have a list called CompanyList

```
var companyList = new List<Company>();
```

I would like to assign name = "Company A", id = "001" to this empty `companyList` variable.

How do I do so?

```
 companyList.FirstOrDefault().Name = "Company A";
 companyList.FirstOrDefault().Id = "001";
```

Comment: You've created a *list* - that doesn't have a name or an ID, that's something that a *company* has. (And the list itself is empty at the moment, too - it contains *no* companies, so there's nothing you can assign a name/id to.) You want something like `companyList.Add(new Company { name = "Company A", id = "001" });`

Comment: `companyList.Add(new Company { Name = "Company A", Id = "001" })`

Comment: Re your edit, using `companyList.FirstOrDefault().Name` will throw a `NullReferenceException` if the list is empty. You need to retrieve the item with `companyList.FirstOrDefault()` and test for null, and only if that's *not* null can you set the properties.

Comment: Note you can also initialize the new `List` with something like `new List<Company>() { new Company { Name = "Company A", Id = "001" } };`

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking that calling `FirstOrDefault` on a `List<Company>` will return an object of type `Company` by "default"? No, that's not the case. When using `FirstOrDefault`, the list must contain items in it in order to return the "first" item, otherwise, it will return `null` (which is the "default").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before you can assign a value to a company in a collection, you must add a company to the collection. You are setting the values of that company, not of the collection itself.

Use either:

```
var companyList = new List<Company>();
companyList.Add(new Company { Name = "Company A", Id = "001" });
```

Or:

```
var companyList = new List<Company>();
companyList.Add(new Company());
// Assumes you want to modify the first company in the list
companyList[0].Name = "Company A";
companyList[0].Id = "001";
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use collection initializer:

```
var companyList = new List<Company>{ new Company { Name = "Company A", Id = "001" } };
```

effectively the same as bellow, a bit more compact

```
var companyList = new List<Company>();
companyList.Add(new Company { Name = "Company A", Id = "001" });
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you simply need to create an instance of `Company` and then add it to your list. Here is an example:

```
List<Company> companyList = new List<Company>();
Company currentCompany = new Company(){id="001", Name="Company A"};
companyList.Add(currentCompany);
```

Side note ** Be aware of using the code snippet denoted in your question

```
 companyList.FirstOrDefault().Name = "Company A";
 companyList.FirstOrDefault().Id = "001";
```

This could lead to uncaught null reference exceptions, crashing your program. Always check for null when using `FirstOrDefault()` to instantiate an object.

```
Company temp = companyList.FirstOrDefault();
if(temp !=null)
{
    temp.Name = "Company A";
    temp.id = "001"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example where you can initialize the collection directly:

```
var companyList = new List<Company> {
    new Company { name = "Company A", id = "001" },
    new Company { name = "Company B", id = "002" }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the list safetly ( without execption ) you shoud do somthing like this :

```
 var company =  companyList.FirstOrDefault() ; 
    if (company != null) {
    company.Name ="aaa";
    company.Id = "123" ;
     }
```